# Message Box as security option (similar to "are you sure you want to delete") GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, messagebox

Alright, i found how to use a message box.

```
 Browser.msgBox('Execute function(experimental)', 'Do you really want to proceed?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
```

What do I have to add, if I want the function aborted when the user presses "NO". ?

Answer (score 0):

[msgBox(title, prompt, buttons)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser?hl=en#msgBox%28String,String,ButtonSet%29). Return: String — lower case text of the button that is clicked by the user.

Example:

```js
function testMsgBox() {
  var _button = Browser.msgBox('Execute function(experimental)', 'Do you really want to proceed?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (_button === 'yes')
    //TODO 'yes'
  else
    //TODO 'no'
}
```